# how to Group results in JQuery UI Autocomplete plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how should i categorize the list?

i'm using jquery 1.5.2 with jquery UI 1.8.5

the api didn't help

```
_renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
                        var that = this,
                            currentCategory = "";
                        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                                currentCategory = item.category;
                            }
                            that._renderItemData(ul, item);
                        });
                    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It was one line:

```
self._renderItemData(ul, item);
```

Now needs to be

```
self._renderItem(ul, item);
```

After I changed it, everything worked fine again. Very frustrating.

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/587618/keith